# Calculating and interpreting effect sizes for interaction terms

Tags: interaction, effect-size

Can an effect size be calculated for an interaction effect in general and more specifically using the F-statistic and its associated degrees of freedom?  If yes, should this be done and what is the appropriate interpretation of the effect size given the nature of interaction effects?  Initially, I assumed the answer is "no." However, a quick Google search turned up statements about computing effect sizes for interaction terms.  Any assistance in clarifying this issue will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into classic old texts (like Geoffrey Keppel's Design and Analysis:  A Researcher's Handbook and Fredric Wolf's Meta-Analysis: Quantitative Methods for Research Synthesis), I've seen several options, including *omega, phi*, and the square of each.  But most widely interpretable and simplest to obtain from most software packages' output is the incremental contribution that the interaction makes to *r*-squared.  Partial *eta* squared (explained variance not shared with any other predictor in the model) is another option, and in fact for an interaction tested in a sequential model, it should be the same as the increment in *r*-squared.  I realize I'm not answering your question about specifically using F and df; if that is that essential to you maybe others can address it.  Wolf shows how to convert *F* to *r* for the 2-group case only, and I'm not the strongest when it comes to formulas.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, an effect size for an interaction can be computed, though I don't think I know any measures of effect size that you can compute simply from the F and df values; usually you need various sums-of-squares values to do the computations. If you have the raw data, the "ezANOVA" function in the ["ez" package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ez/index.html) for R will give you [generalized eta square](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14664681), a measure of effect size that, unlike partial-eta square, generalizes across design types (eg. within-Ss designs vs between-Ss designs).